# Batch Class hitting HeapSize limit

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

have written batch class to do some calculation with Opportunities under each Account and after the calculation some needs to be updated in the Account Object.
there are some Account which has 25k plus opportunities in it. Please have look : -

```
global class ScheduleOpportunitySummariesOnAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Schedulable{

    public String query;

    public ScheduleOpportunitySummariesOnAccount() {

    }

    public ScheduleOpportunitySummariesOnAccount(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('query++++'+query);
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<Account> scope) {


        Map<Id,List<Opportunity> > oppMap;
        Set<Id> accSet= new Set<Id>();
        for(Account a : scope)
        {
            accSet.add(a.Id);
        }
        oppMap = ScheduleOpportunitySummariesOnAccount.getRelatedOpportunity( accSet);

        System.debug('scope++++'+scope);
        summaryOnAccount(scope , oppMap );
    }

    private void summaryOnAccount(list<Account> scope , Map<Id,List<Opportunity> > oppMap ) {

        List<Account> updateAccountList = new List<Account>();
        Account acc;
        String zipcodes;
        Set<String> zipSets;
        Set<Id> partnerIdSet;
        Integer counter;
        for(Account itm : scope) {
            System.debug(itm);
            System.debug('Heap'+Limits.getHeapSize()+' of '+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
            acc = new Account();

            acc.Id = itm.Id;
            acc.Total_of_Orders__c = 0;
            acc.Total_of_Completed_Orders__c = 0;
            acc.Total_of_Cancelled_Orders__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Amount_of_Orders_ALL__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Amount_of_Completed_Orders__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Amount_of_Cancelled_Orders__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Partners_Ordered_From__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Order_Tip__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Delivery_Fee__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Tax__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Sub_Total__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Discounts_Applied__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Credits_Applied__c = 0;
            acc.Total_GreenRush_Commission_Earned__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Vendor_Payouts__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Order_Discount_Reimbursements__c = 0;
            acc.Total_Order_Credit_Reimbursements__c = 0;
            acc.Total_gL_Completed_Orders__c = 0;
            acc.Total_mP_Completed_Orders__c = 0;
            acc.Total_mP_Completed_Orders_Last_30__c = 0;
            zipcodes = '';

            zipSets = new set<String>();
            partnerIdSet = new Set<Id>();
            counter = 0 ;
            Date dateOfSecondOrder ;
            System.debug('Heap'+Limits.getHeapSize()+' of '+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
            if( OppMap.containsKey(itm.Id) ){
                for(Opportunity opp : oppMap.get( itm.Id ) ) {
                    partnerIdSet.add(opp.Dispensary__c);
                    if(String.isNotBlank(opp.Delivery_Zip_Code__c)){
                        zipSets.add(opp.Delivery_Zip_Code__c);
                    } 


                    acc.Total_of_Orders__c++;
                    acc.Total_Amount_of_Orders_ALL__c += opp.Order_Total_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Total_Amount__c;

                    if(opp.Order_Status__c == 'Complete') {
                        acc.Total_of_Completed_Orders__c++;
                        acc.Total_Amount_of_Completed_Orders__c += opp.Order_Total_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Total_Amount__c;
                        acc.First_Complete_Client_Order__c = opp.Order_Created_Date_Time__c ;

                    }
                    if(opp.Order_Status__c != null && opp.GreenRush_Order_Badge__c != null && !opp.Order_Status__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Cancelled') && opp.GreenRush_Order_Badge__c.equalsIgnoreCase('greenLabel') ){
                        acc.Total_gL_Completed_Orders__c = acc.Total_gL_Completed_Orders__c + 1;
                    }else if(opp.Order_Status__c != null && opp.GreenRush_Order_Badge__c != null && !opp.Order_Status__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Cancelled') && (opp.GreenRush_Order_Badge__c.equalsIgnoreCase('greenRush') || opp.GreenRush_Order_Badge__c.equalsIgnoreCase('Reseller'))){
                        acc.Total_mP_Completed_Orders__c = acc.Total_mP_Completed_Orders__c + 1;
                        if(opp.Order_Created_Date_Time__c.date().daysBetween(System.today()) <= 30){
                            acc.Total_mP_Completed_Orders_Last_30__c = acc.Total_mP_Completed_Orders_Last_30__c + 1 ;    
                        }
                    }

                    if(counter == 0){
                        acc.Last_Order_Value__c = opp.Order_Sub_Total__c!=NULL ? opp.Order_Sub_Total__c : 0.00 ;
                        if(opp.Order_Created_Date_Time__c!=null)
                            acc.Date_Of_Last_Order__c = opp.Order_Created_Date_Time__c.date();
                    } 
                    if(counter == oppMap.get( itm.Id ).size() - 1){
                        if(opp.Order_Created_Date_Time__c!=null)
                            acc.Date_of_First_Order__c = opp.Order_Created_Date_Time__c.date();
                        if(dateOfSecondOrder!=NULL){
                            acc.of_Days_Btwn_1_2_Order__c = opp.Order_Created_Date_Time__c.date().daysBetween(dateOfSecondOrder);
                        }
                    }
                    if(acc.Date_of_First_Order__c!=NULL && acc.Total_of_Completed_Orders__c!=NULL){

                        acc.mP_Orders_Day_Live__c = acc.Total_of_Completed_Orders__c /(acc.Date_of_First_Order__c.daysBetween(system.today())) ;
                    }

                    if(counter == oppMap.get(itm.Id).size() - 2){
                        dateOfSecondOrder = opp.Order_Created_Date_Time__c.date();
                    }

                    if(opp.Order_Status__c == 'Cancelled') {
                        acc.Total_of_Cancelled_Orders__c++;
                        acc.Total_Amount_of_Cancelled_Orders__c += opp.Order_Total_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Total_Amount__c;
                    }

                    acc.Total_Order_Tip__c += opp.Order_Tip_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Tip_Amount__c;
                    acc.Total_Delivery_Fee__c += opp.Order_Delivery_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Delivery_Amount__c;
                    acc.Total_Tax__c += opp.Order_Tax_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Tax_Amount__c;
                    acc.Total_Sub_Total__c += opp.Order_Sub_Total__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Sub_Total__c;
                    acc.Total_Discounts_Applied__c += opp.Order_Discount_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Discount_Amount__c;
                    acc.Total_Credits_Applied__c += opp.Order_Credits_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Credits_Amount__c;
                    acc.Total_GreenRush_Commission_Earned__c += opp.Total_Commission_Earned__c == null ? 0 : opp.Total_Commission_Earned__c;
                    acc.Total_Vendor_Payouts__c += opp.Total_Owed_to_Vendor__c == null ? 0 : opp.Total_Owed_to_Vendor__c;
                    acc.Total_Order_Discount_Reimbursements__c += opp.Order_Discount_Reimbursment_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Discount_Reimbursment_Amount__c;
                    acc.Total_Order_Credit_Reimbursements__c += opp.Order_Credits_Reimbursment_Amount__c == null ? 0 : opp.Order_Credits_Reimbursment_Amount__c;
                    counter = counter + 1 ;
                }

            }
            System.debug('Heap'+Limits.getHeapSize()+' of '+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
            if(!zipSets.isEmpty()){
                for(String key : zipSets){
                    zipcodes = zipcodes + key + ',';
                }    
            }

            acc.Zip_Codes_Delivered_To__c = String.isNotBlank(zipcodes) ? zipcodes.substring(0, zipcodes.lastIndexOf(',')) : '';

            acc.Total_Partners_Ordered_From__c = partnerIdSet.size();
            acc.Total_Order_Reimbursements__c = acc.Total_Order_Discount_Reimbursements__c + acc.Total_Order_Credit_Reimbursements__c;

            System.debug('acc'+acc);
            updateAccountList.add(acc);
            System.debug('Heap'+Limits.getHeapSize()+' of '+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
            acc = null;
            zipcodes = null;
            zipSets = null;
            partnerIdSet = null;
            counter = null;
        }
        System.debug('Heap'+Limits.getHeapSize()+' of '+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
        System.debug(updateAccountList);
        update updateAccountList;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        DateTime curr = DateTime.now();

        DateTime startTime = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(curr.year(), curr.month(), curr.day(), 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime endTime = startTime.addDays(1).addSeconds(-1);

        String st = String.valueOf(startTime);
        st = st.replace(' ','T');

        String et = String.valueOf(endTime);
        et = et.replace(' ','T');


        query = ' Select Id, Total_of_Orders__c, Total_of_Completed_Orders__c, Total_of_Cancelled_Orders__c, Total_Amount_of_Orders_ALL__c,'
            + '        Total_Amount_of_Completed_Orders__c, Total_Amount_of_Cancelled_Orders__c, Total_Partners_Ordered_From__c, Total_Order_Tip__c,'
            + '        Total_Delivery_Fee__c, Total_Tax__c, Total_Sub_Total__c, Total_Discounts_Applied__c, Total_Credits_Applied__c, Total_GreenRush_Commission_Earned__c,'
            + '        Total_Vendor_Payouts__c, Total_Order_Discount_Reimbursements__c, Total_Order_Credit_Reimbursements__c, of_Days_Btwn_1_2_Order__c,'
            + '        RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name '
            + ' From Account where IsPersonAccount = false '  ;

        System.debug(query);
        ScheduleOpportunitySummariesOnAccount batch = new ScheduleOpportunitySummariesOnAccount(query);

        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batch,20);
    }

    private static Map<Id,List<Opportunity> > getRelatedOpportunity( Set<Id> accSet ){
        System.debug('Heap'+Limits.getHeapSize()+' of '+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
        //List<Opportunity> oppResult = new List<Opportunity>();
        //List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        Map<Id,List<Opportunity> > oppMap = new Map<Id,List<Opportunity> >();
        /*List<Account> accountidList = new List<Account>();
        accountidList.addAll( accountscope );*/
        String oppquery =  '   Select Id,GreenRush_Order_Badge__c ,Order_Credits_Amount__c, Order_Credits_Reimbursment_Amount__c, Order_Delivery_Amount__c, Delivery_Zip_Code__c,Order_Created_Date_Time__c,'
            + '                Order_Discount_Amount__c, Order_Discount_Reimbursment_Amount__c, Order_Status__c, Order_Sub_Total__c, Dispensary__c,'
            + '                Order_Tax_Amount__c, Order_Tip_Amount__c, Order_Total_Amount__c, Total_Commission_Earned__c, Total_Owed_to_Vendor__c' 
            + '                From Opportunity where Dispensary__c in : accSet ORDER BY Order_Created_Date_Time__c DESC' ;




        for( Opportunity opp_obj : Database.query( oppquery) ){
            if( oppMap.containsKey( opp_obj.Dispensary__c ) ){
                /*oppList  = oppMap.get( opp_obj.Dispensary__c ) ;
                oppList.add( opp_obj );
                oppMap.put( opp_obj.Dispensary__c , oppList ) ;*/
                oppMap.get( opp_obj.Dispensary__c).add(opp_obj) ;
            }else{
                /*oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
                oppList.add( opp_obj );
                oppMap.put( opp_obj.Dispensary__c , oppList ) ;*/
                oppMap.put( opp_obj.Dispensary__c, new List<Opportunity>{opp_obj}) ;
            }
        }

        System.debug('Heap'+Limits.getHeapSize()+' of '+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
        return oppMap ;
    }
}
```

can someone help me on this. is there any other way to construct this batch class??

Comment: Either you can optimize the code further or reduce the batch size that doesn't cross the heap size limit.

Comment: but how....do you have any logic??please suggest...

Comment: This class is... not really going to work. However, short term, just lower the number of items in the batch eg `Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batch,2);`

Comment: what will be the structure which will work...tell me structure ..i'll figure it out.

Comment: Instead of creating the `Map<Id,List<Opportunity> > oppMap;` and iterating over each opportunity to sum the value you can try to create a map with accId and Integer by doing `AggregateResult` query on Opp and group by Opp.AccId

Comment: not possible ....there are some fields which has Divide function...which we can't do in Aggregateresult query..

Comment: Only option then might be to reduce the batch size or else instead of holding the `List<Opportunity>` in map create some kind of wrapper that holds only the required data that might reduce some heap size.

Answer (score 1):

I see that `getRelatedOpportunity()` method actually repopulates the passed account's opportunities and put that in a map of (`Id , List<Opportunity>`) , is it possible for you to write related Query like  instead of step:

```
oppMap = ScheduleOpportunitySummariesOnAccount.getRelatedOpportunity( accSet);
```

can you replace it by single query and loop through that , like:

```
//sample 
[SELECT id , (SELECT id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE id IN:accSet];
```

This will give you , all the related opportunities , then you can reduce the processing time on this method:

```
ScheduleOpportunitySummariesOnAccount.getRelatedOpportunity( accSet);
```

1. There are lot of default assignments that you have done , see if you can assign default values to the field so that you need not explicitly assign the values in your code.
2. There are few lines of your summaryAccount method which can be optimized like eg: using roll-up summary (for  `acc.Total_of_Orders__c++;` [i assume this refers to total orders for accounts] )